# How to detect if user is using an app or browser to access my site?

Tags: php, android, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile

Hi guys i'm using a video cms script which has a desktop version and a mobile fallback version. The user agent is detected by a file named detect.php and directs the user either to the desktop version or the mobile version of the site. I created a webview app (both android and ios) which I have advertisements in so I want to keep mobile users locked into those apps and remove access if they don't have the app by redirecting them to install my app. I've seen a few suggestions but they don't take into account hybrid sites and I fear that I may end up redirecting people who use my apps into an infinite loop to install an app they already have. Below I have provided my detect.php code...I have also taken a look at google analytics and see safari, safari-in-app, android, etc. So i'm not exactly sure how to take the approach for this because of the many factors involved.

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$useragent = trim(strtolower($useragent));
$new_URL = str_replace("www.", '', _URL);
$new_URL_MOBI = str_replace("www.", '', _URL_MOBI);
$current_URL = str_replace("www.", '', "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$current_URL_device = strpos($current_URL, $new_URL_MOBI);
$device_url = ($current_URL_device === false) ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';

if ( ! defined('COOKIE_DEVICE'))
{
    define('COOKIE_DEVICE', 'melody_device');
}

if(isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_DEVICE]))
{
    if ($_COOKIE[COOKIE_DEVICE] != $device_url)
    {
        if ($device_url == 'mobile')
        {
            $takemehome = str_replace($new_URL_MOBI, $new_URL, $current_URL);
            header("Location: ".$takemehome."");
            exit;
        }
        elseif ($device_url == 'desktop')
        {
            $takemehome = str_replace($new_URL, $new_URL_MOBI, $current_URL);
            header("Location: ".$takemehome."");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if (strpos($useragent, "iphone") !== false || strpos($useragent, "symbianos") !== false || strpos($useragent, "ipad") !== false || strpos($useragent, "nook") !== false || strpos($useragent, "kindle") !== false || strpos($useragent, "IEMobile") !== false || strpos($useragent, "windows phone") !== false || strpos($useragent, "ipod") !== false || strpos($useragent, "android") !== false || strpos($useragent, "blackberry") !== false || strpos($useragent, "samsung") !== false || strpos($useragent, "nokia") !== false || strpos($useragent, "windows ce") !== false || strpos($useragent, "sonyericsson") !== false || strpos($useragent, "webos") !== false || strpos($useragent, "wap") !== false || strpos($useragent, "motor") !== false || strpos($useragent, "symbian") !== false || strpos($useragent, "android") !== false)
       {
          $device = 'mobile';
          setcookie(COOKIE_DEVICE, $device, time() + 84000, COOKIE_PATH);

          if (strpos($current_URL, $new_URL_MOBI) === false)
          {
             //User is NOT on mobile site, redirect
             $takemehome = str_replace($new_URL, $new_URL_MOBI, $current_URL);
             header("Location: ".$takemehome."");
             exit;
          }
          //Continue as usual
       }
       else
       {
          $device = 'desktop';
          setcookie(COOKIE_DEVICE, $device, time() + 84000, COOKIE_PATH);

          if (strpos($current_URL, $new_URL_MOBI) !== false)
          {
             //User IS on mobile site, redirect
             $takemehome = str_replace($new_URL_MOBI, $new_URL, $current_URL);
             header("Location: ".$takemehome."");
             exit;
          }
          //Continue as usual
       }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have not in fact provided any relevant code.

Comment: Why not rewrite the apps to bypass the `detect.php` page?

Comment: @Bmargulies what code would you like?

Comment: @nhgrif sadly I can't because there is a factor of windows and blackberry users who I do not provide apps for.

Comment: There was no code at all when I added that comment.

Answer (score 0):

**you can't**. When an user access to your website from the app, **he use in any case the standard browser of the device** (in iOS it is Safari). So, you can to know this, **just if the app is a your app** which you can develop *ad hoc* by sending an **extra POST or GET data** to uncover if access is from your app.

In general, as i say, you can't.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll have to use a pop up asking if they are using the app or would like to install it.

Comment: yes maybe is better :)
Please close the topic by setting favorite answer.
Thank you.

Comment: I just read that I can set a specific user agent within my apps and then direct everything else to my app installation instead.

Comment: Yes, for your app as i say above, you can to do what you want.